# How do you build a docker image if you only have a shell installer for a java application?

Tags: java, linux, shell, docker

I'm new to docker and want to understand on how to build a docker image that I can deploy in my organization's internal cloud

Currently, our vendor has provided us with a shell script which we use to install a java application on a VM.

Is there any way to build an image for this java application using this shell script?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your
way arround here. Also I suggest you check how to [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), specifically how to create minimal, complete and verifiable examples. 
These guidelines will help you get better answers in the future. Good luck with your coding!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just use

`FROM <base_image>`
to define the base image you want to start with (i.e. the best suited environement for you application to work: typically you would use Ubuntu 16.04, or maybe an Alpine linux distribution if you want to be more lightweight

then

`RUN <shell-script>`
to install you application
(note that if there are dependencies needed for the script to run (like JAVA), you will need to RUN the install steps for the dependencies *before* this RUN command)

and then

`CMD <command-to-start-the-app>`
to start the app.

A good place to start with Docker is to look up the official images of known services on github and see how they do it.
There are many images using JAVA, with a base like https://github.com/dockerfile/java